# Google mobile vision iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-vision

https://developers.google.com/vision/ios/text-overview
the link refers to Objective C implementation. Can anyone help me out for Swift Version?

I have tried using the above code, but the delegates are somehow not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile vision is deprecated. It is now a part of `Firebase` as `MLVision`, and that's what you're probably looking for...

Use:

```
pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
# If using an on-device API:
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'
```

I have tried the on-device text recognition module recently and it works like a charm

Suggest you to go through this link for documentation:-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/recognize-text